# Why doesn't my form show a validation error?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to perform a simple task. I want to validate a form or show a message stating 'Please complete the form!' What am I overlooking because all works except the message? How can I achieve this or am I simply just missing something? I have tried placing the script at the top and bottom,  but I want on the bottom because I want the page to load faster and not pause for the JS.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <!--[if it IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![end if]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>

<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div><label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required></div>

        <div><label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></div>

        <div><label for="submit"></label><input type="submit" value="Login &rarr;" id="submit"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="login.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function validateForm() {
    'use strict';


    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');


    if ( (email.value.length > 0) && (password.value.length > 0) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Please complete the form!');
        return false;
    }

} 


function init() {
    'use strict';


    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
        loginForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    }

} 
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it, since you use `window.onload` to initialize it.

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bwuzeg1o/2/ I had to remove the `required` attributes, because those prevent it from trying to submit the form, so the submit handler doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your own validation instead of the browser's built-in checking for required fields, remove the `required` attributes from your `<input>` tags.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bwuzeg1o/2/)

Comment: Wow, perfect thank you. I thought I was going crazy.